# Is there a way to set/Change CMIS repository's capabilities?

Tags: java, apache, cmis, document-repository

I am using CMIS services for accessing a document repository using JAVA. 
I would like to know, if there is a way in which I can change the capabilities of the repo? Example, I would like to change the Query Capabilities from "MetadataOnly" to "BothCombined". How is this possible programatically?
There are no setters for these. There is only one getRepositoyCapabilities().

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot change the capabilities unless you are the developer of the repository. Those are meant for the repository to declare what its capabilities are. If your repository says it supports "MetadataOnly" queries then you cannot simply change it to "BothCombined" to allow you to query for both metadata and full-text because the underlying repository lacks that capability.

If you have more questions about capabilities, see the [CMIS Specification](http://docs.oasis-open.org/cmis/CMIS/v1.1/CMIS-v1.1.html).